# How I can change the title of SendFriend page

Tags: magento2

I've enabled functional, but there is not title by default.

I see only site **suffix**, like **mySite's** **suffix**.
and url like `/sendfriend/product/send/id/2059/cat_id/47/`

Where is the place of configuring of page title?

Comment: it's located under Content > Configuration > > Other Settings and then HTML Head section and here you can add a Title suffix

Answer (score 1):

Try below way.

Find the file in below location.

> /vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/mailto.phtml

And past file in below location.

> /app/design/frontend/theme_name/frontend/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/mailto.phtml

Replace your code with below one.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct() ?>
<?php if ($block->canEmailToFriend()): ?>
    <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product')->getEmailToFriendUrl($_product) ?>"
       class="action mailto friend" title="Send a friend"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Email') ?></span></a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: I have no difference between original file and above.